# fgetcsv lines with extra delimiter enclosed in double quotes

Tags: escaping, double-quotes, fgetcsv

I have this page in which a user uploads a CSV and then using PHP an existing MySQL table is truncated and the values from CSV are added to the table.

Until now I used phpMyAdmin through Import CSV method, but I want to provide the user with a page so that they can upload the file themself.

The structure of the CSV is like this

```
code, name, price
102, plane toy, 23.7
```

99% of lines are the same except some of them are enclosed in double quotation marks by the software in the shop from which the user exports the CSV.
Like this:

```
223, "Mary's white, tshirt", 23.9
```

This is where my import fails, it reaches the ',' in "'s white, tshirt".

I found here on SO a way to buff out the characters but it was for a scenario where the pattern is the same, mine changes, I do not know where the extra "," will be but I do have those items which contain extra "," enclosed in double quotation marks "item".

How can I modify my code to bypass the issue?

Here is my code:

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
         $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
        
         $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);
        
         if(strtolower($chk_ext[1]) == "csv")
         {
        
             $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
             $handle = fopen($filename, "r");

             $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','xxxx','zzzz','zzz');
                if (!$con)
              {
              die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
              }

            mysqli_select_db($con,"TABLE 1");
            $sqltruncate = "TRUNCATE TABLE `TABLE 1`";
            mysqli_query($con,$sqltruncate) or die(mysqli_error($con));
            
       
             while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE)
             {
                $sql = "INSERT into `TABLE 1`(code,name,price) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[24]')";
                mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
             }
       
             fclose($handle);
             echo "Success";
         }
         else
         {
             echo "Invalid file";
         }   
    }
    ?>

    
    <form action='<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

        Choose CSV : <input type='file' name='sel_file' id='sel_file'>
        <input type='submit' name='submit' value='submit'>

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a foreach inside the while and then use an trim() to remove the quotes from the values.